# SFDX: Create a Default Scratch Org... failed to run

Tags: developer

ERROR:  The signup request failed because this organization has reached its active scratch org limit.
11:13:42.653 sfdx force:org:create -f config\project-scratch-def.json --setalias treailhead --durationdays 30 --setdefaultusername ended with exit code 1

above the error are occured every time . please help me any one out there

Answer (score 15):

There is 2 ways you can delete the scratch org.

**First is from UI**

In Dev Hub, ActiveScratchOrgs represent the scratch orgs that are currently in use. ScratchOrgInfos represent the requests that were used to create scratch orgs and provide historical context.

- Log in to Dev Hub org as the System Administrator or as a user with the Salesforce DX permissions.
  From the App Launcher, select Active Scratch Org to see a list of all active scratch orgs.
  To view more details about a scratch org, click the link in the Number column.
- To delete an active scratch org from the Active Scratch Org list view, choose Delete from the dropdown.
  Deleting an active scratch org does not delete the request (ScratchOrgInfo) that created it, but it does free up a scratch org so that it doesn’t count against your allocations.

[Manage Scratch Orgs from Dev Hub](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_view_lex.htm)

**Second using CLI**

```
sfdx force:org:delete -u me@my.org
```

You can check command reference [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_org.htm)